# WebLogic 10.3.4 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am having issues with deploying my WebLogic 10.3.4 Hibernate / Spring application.  I am getting the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()`

I read about the prefer-application-resources and tried that in my weblogic.xml file.  Unfortunately, even after adding the packages, it still isn't working.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?  Thanks in advance!

WebLogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.javax.persistence.OneToMany</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:prefer-application-resources>
            <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.javax.persistence.*</wls:resource-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-resources>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.5</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>ncms2</wls:context-root>
    <wls:resource-description>
        <wls:res-ref-name>NCS</wls:res-ref-name>
        <wls:jndi-name>NCS</wls:jndi-name>
    </wls:resource-description>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by (something may be not necessary, please try )

1/ Using EAR

2/ at weblogic.xml at WAR,

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages> 
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

3/ at weblogic-application.xml

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```